# Sapper/Svelte SASS preprocessing?

Tags: npm, svelte

So I was checking out the realworld implementation of Sapper/Svelte: https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld

I've read a lot about SASS preprocessing, and it doesn't seem like it is fully supported, but there are some docs on it. From what I could put together, I should be able to preprocess my  tags after I made the following modifications to my `webpack.client.config.js` file:

```
const svelte = require('rollup-plugin-svelte');
const sass = require('svelte-preprocess-sass').sass;

const config = require('sapper/webpack/config.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: config.client.entry(),
    output: config.client.output(),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'svelte-loader',
                    options: {
                        hydratable: true,
                        emitCss: !config.dev,
                        cascade: false,
                        store: true
                    }
                }
            },
            config.dev && {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            !config.dev && {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: config.dev } }]
                })
            }
        ].filter(Boolean)
    },
    plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: {
        style: sass(),
      }
    }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'main',
            async: true,
            children: true
        }),
        config.dev && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        !config.dev && new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'),
        !config.dev && new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        !config.dev && new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    devtool: config.dev ? 'inline-source-map' : false
};
```

I keep getting the following error:

> node server.js
>   realworldsapper/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375
>   arguments[i].apply(this);

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing and matching Rollup and webpack, which are two different module bundlers — you're adding rollup-plugin-svelte to a webpack config, and webpack doesn't know what to do with it so it throws an error.

Instead, use svelte-preprocess-sass inside the svelte-loader config:

```
use: {
  loader: 'svelte-loader',
  options: {
    hydratable: true,
    emitCss: !config.dev,
    cascade: false,
    store: true,
    style: sass()
  }
}
```

(Note that the `style: sass()` line will become `preprocess: { style: sass() }` in a future version of svelte-loader — see [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader/issues/41)).

By the way, it looks like you're using an older version of Sapper — there have been some major improvements recently, so it's worth upgrading to 0.9. Unfortunately it does mean making some changes to your project structure (see the [migration guide](https://sapper.svelte.technology/guide#0-6-to-0-7) for the details, or reclone [sapper-template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template) and copy your `routes` folder over).

Comment: Ah, I've just re-read the question and you're looking at the svelte-realworld project. We'll have to update *that* to the newest Sapper! It's a bit out of date and misleading at the moment.

Comment: I actually tried what you are saying here and even after wrapping my SASS code in `<style type="text/scss"></style>`, I am getting parse errors.

   Module build failed: Error: ParseError: Identifier is expected (12:8)
10:         flex-wrap: wrap;
11:         justify-content: space-between;
12:         .product-card {
            ^
13:             font-size: 10px;
14:         }
    at preprocess.then.catch.err (/Users/justin.dasilva/Sites/sapper/node_modules/svelte-loader/index.js:100:12)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: It would be great if you did update the svelte-realworld project. My team at work has currently split up into 4 groups to investigate different frontend frameworks for the next version of our project. 1. Latest Angular, 2. React, 3. Vue and 4. Sapper (Me)
So far I'm very enthusiastic about Sapper. The one thing our project definitely needs is the SASS support, so I'm hoping to get that into my demo before I share it with the team.

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to keep all the SASS related files separate from the HTML files. Or at least support that option. I could create a gulp process that creates a CSS file from SASS files, but it would be nice if this gulp process was tied into the hotmodule reload. Is there any examples of this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `exclude: /node_modules/` to each of your rules:

`test: /\.css$/,
exclude: /node_modules/, // <- Add this`

This ensures that transpilation is not applied to any of the files in the node_modules folder.